# Swift: How to define a UIView delegate with unowned(unsafe) reference?

Tags: swift, delegates

I find the following code in `UITableView` class,

```
unowned(unsafe) var delegate: UITableViewDelegate?
```

so I wander how to define a `unowned(unsafe)` reference delegate for `UIView`, then I encounter the following error when I write the unowned(unsafe) keyword in my class,

```
/Users/larryhou/Documents/Xcode/AtomicElements/AtomicElements/AtomicElementView.swift:32:25: 'unowned' cannot be applied to non-class type 'AtomicElementViewDelegate?'

protocol AtomicElementViewDelegate:NSObjectProtocol
{
    func didTap(target:AtomicElementView, sender:UITapGestureRecognizer)
}
```

I can only use `weak` keyword, but I want keep the reference until `UIView` is deallocated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those two designations - `unowned` and `weak` - are equivalent from the perspective of references. Where they differ is the presumption of existence - in Swift, unowned instances are presumed to *always* exist as long as reference to them does, whereas weak instances are optionals - they may exist, or they may not, so you need to use optional chaining or some other means of working with them.

In UIKit, the delegate pattern with `UIView` subclasses is to declare them as `weak` because the delegate is nearly always the view controller that owns the view that the subclass is a subview of. Declaring a delegate as strongly referenced in that situation would set up a reference cycle, hence delegates are typically declared with the `weak` keyword. If you have a different situation, you can allow your delegate to be strongly referenced by simply leaving out the `weak` keyword.

In this particular case, `unowned (unsafe)` is an artifact of being bridged from ObjC.

Answer (score 2):

> how to define a unowned(unsafe) reference delegate for UIView

You can't. And you shouldn't want to. `unowned(unsafe)` is a way of expressing the Objective-C *non-ARC* `assign` policy, i.e. no memory management. It is horrible and dangerous (and can cause crashes). The name tells you what the problem is. It is unsafe!!! There is no Swift equivalent because Swift has built-in memory management. This is one of the reasons why Swift is good. Don't worry be happy.

But do be careful, because this designation is warning you that if the delegate goes out of existence while the UITableView still exists, you will crash because the table view will not know this and may try to send a message to the non-existent delegate.

Comment: You can read my book on this topic if you're really curious: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch12.html#_property_memory_management_policies But there is little reason to know about this if you're going to be using Swift!